# select row and children

Tags: css, selector, parent-child

I can select a `tr`.

I can select a `tr`'s children.

How do I select a `tr` *and* its' children?

For example, I want to change the `background-color` of an entire row and its' children when either the row or any of its' children are hovered.

I can do either.  I can't do both.

Many thanks in advance!

**Specificity**

I should've added that I want to include *all* children such as inputs.

Definitely should've been clearer.  :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tr:hover, td:hover, tr:hover td {
   background-color:green;
}
```

for other children either do

```
tr:hover, td:hover, tr:hover * {
   background-color:green;
}
```

witch will work for all children (you might get unwanted results with this thought...)

or, be more specific, and list all children in witch you actually want the effect to ocur

ex:

```
tr:hover, td:hover, tr:hover td, , tr:hover input[text], tr:hover .myHoverClass {
   background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you hover over a child of a `tr` you effectively hover over the `tr` as well, so all you need to target is the highest element (*the `tr`*)

```
tr:hover,
tr:hover td{
   background-color:red;
}
```